# Go lang : search x digits from sets of numbers, why takes very long time to execute?

Tags: algorithm, go

I tried to make small programs that ***find x digits from sets of numbers***, for example : i want to find **89th** digits from **1 - 1000000000**.

Here is my code : https://play.golang.org/p/93yh_urX16

```
package main

import (

    "fmt"
    "strconv"

)

var bucket string

func main() {

    findDigits( 89, 1000000000 )

}

func findDigits( digits int, length int) {

    for i := 1; i <= length; i++ {

        bucket += strconv.Itoa(i)

    }

    fmt.Println( "The", digits, "th digit from 1", "-", length, "is :", string ( [] rune ( bucket )[digits - 1] ) )

}
```

Does anyone knows, what mistakes i've made ? i need some advice to me for improving this code.

Thanks :)

Comment: I don't know go that well, but if `int` is a 32 bit integer your `length` doesn't actually fit into it; You'd get an integer overflow, probably resulting in a negative number, which means your loop never terminates. If it _does_ fit... well, why would you expect that performing 10 billion operations - even if they're fairly trivial - should be fast? Why do you put 10 billion numbers in a bucket if you only want the 89th one? Note that storing 10 billion 32 bit numbers requires almost 40GB of space, which is more than most workstations can store even with swap space.

Comment: int is 64 bits on a 64 bit computer. Also I think the compiler will warn you that the constant wouldn't fit in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your program](https://play.golang.org/p/93yh_urX16) is very, very inefficient. [user1431317's program](http://play.golang.org/p/Kj_sfsSpo-) is very inefficient.

Simply calculate the value. It will only take nanoseconds of CPU time and a few memory allocations, even for a digit index as large as 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (95.6 nanoseconds and 2 allocations on my computer). For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "strconv"
)

// digit returns the ith digit from the sequence of
// concatenated non-negative integers.
// The sequence of digits is 01234567891011121314151617181920...
func digit(i int64) string {
    // There are 9 one digit positive integers, 90 two digit,
    // 900 three digit, and so on.
    if i <= 0 {
        return "0"
    }
    j := int64(1)
    w := 1
    for ; ; w++ {
        t := j + 9*int64(math.Pow10(w-1))*int64(w)
        if 0 > t || t > i {
            break
        }
        j = t
    }
    k := i - j
    n := k / int64(w)
    m := k % int64(w)
    d := strconv.FormatInt(int64(math.Pow10(w-1))+n, 10)[m]
    return string(d)
}

func main() {
    tests := []int64{
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
        10, 11, 12, 13,
        88, 89,
        188, 189, 190, 191, 192,
        math.MaxInt32, math.MaxInt64,
    }
    for _, n := range tests {
        fmt.Println(n, digit(n))
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
10 1
11 0
12 1
13 1
88 4
89 9
188 9
189 9
190 1
191 0
192 0
2147483647 2
9223372036854775807 9
```